# Making very simple html page cross-browser compatible with CSS

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, pre

I have this "web-site" -> http://www.krlja-ustvari.hr

It works 'perfect' in Google Chrome. By 'perfect' I mean that content is always 100% width and 100% height, overflown stuff is hidden and line breaks are made without `<br />` tags. That's exactly what I need.
However, when I look at the same page in Firefox or Internet Explorer (didn't check with other browsers) I can see vertical scroll bar. That's exactly what I don't want.

My question is simple: how to make this page render in all browsers like in Google Chrome?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: I would first suggest re-setting your CSS so it is on the same page across all browsers. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ or http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

Comment: Whoa, didn't know about this! I will look into it for sure! Many thanks for this useful information!

Comment: bad news, it doesn't appear, let alone render, in Symbian's built-in browser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you do not need scrollbars in the body/document at all

```
   <style type="text/css">

   body { overflow:hidden; }
   </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you change the `min-height:100%` declaration on #content to just `height:100%`, you should be fine in those other browsers.

That worked when I edited your page in Firebug for FF.

Comment: This one also worked. Thanks a lot but I will accept Rob's answer because he was first :) Will make this answer useful too :)